# Unable to allocate memory inside a C function

Tags: c, memory

I am trying to get stdin of unknown length using C. I have tried the below code. But it says unable to allocate memory. Can anyone tell me the reasons for it.

```
size_t len=sizeof(chunk);
char *read=malloc(len);
size_t len_chunk;

read[0]='\0';

do{
    fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk),stdin);
    len_chunk = strlen(chunk);
    size_t len_read= strlen(read);

    if(len-len_read<len_chunk)
    {
        len *= 2;
        if ((read = realloc(read, len))==NULL)
        {
            perror("Unable to allocate memory");
            free(read);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    strcpy(read+len_read, chunk);
    len_read+=len_chunk;

}while(chunk[len_chunk-2]!='\n');
```

Comment: What is `chunk`? How is it defined? Also, calling your variable `read` is a bad idea: `read()` is a standard library function.

Comment: If `realloc` fails and return `NULL` then you do `free(read)`, but by that point `read` is a null pointer. Never assign back to the same pointer you pass to `realloc`.

Comment: Note that the 'error recovery' call `free(read)` is a no-op; you've lost the original pointer because you misused `realloc()` and overwrote `read` with a null pointer.  You should use `void *new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr == NULL) { free(old_ptr); p_error(…); exit(1); } old_ptr = new_ptr; old_size = new_size;` or something very similar.

Comment: And if you want to read a full line but don't know the exact size of each line, then it might actually be easier to read character by character and append to the buffer, reallocating as needed (which can be checked by the current position to add the character equals the current size of the buffer).

Comment: chunk is a char array.  ```char chunk[16];```

Comment: I suspect an off-by-1 with `if(len-len_read<len_chunk)` does not properly account for the memory needed for the _null character_.  Hmmmm  Perhaps `if(len-len_read<=len_chunk)`

Comment: `while(chunk[len_chunk-2]!='\n');` is certainly amiss.  Try `while(chunk[len_chunk-1]!='\n');`

Comment: Tip: Check return value of input functions like `fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk),stdin);`.  If it returns `NULL`, exit the loop.  Else code errantly loops forever eventually running out of memory.

Comment: ```if(len-len_read<=len_chunk)```  this worked for me